# Securing kubernetes with iptables

Tags: iptables, kubernetes

I got a project to createa a development kubernetes cluster on a bunch of servers that only have public ip's. I am wondering what can I do with iptables in order to limit the public access of the server and still have it up and running.

I have tried the following template:

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2916:273018]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "ssh access" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
{% for host in groups.all %}
-A INPUT -s {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}/32 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6443 -m comment --comment "ACCEPT INTER CLUSTER CONNECTIVITY ON PORT 6443" -j ACCEPT
{% endfor %}
{% for host in groups.all %}
-A INPUT -s {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}/32 -m comment --comment "ACCEPT INTER CLUSTER CONNECTIVITY" -j ACCEPT
{% endfor %}

COMMIT
```

but then pods were not starting and I could not exec into the pod containers.

Comment: You need to provide much mote details and determine your exact needs. Using `iptables`, you can do many things. Mainly, it can be used as firewall to allow / deny specific IP and/or ports (services).

Comment: I have updated the question with a iptables template that was not successful before.

Comment: Are you using specific tutorial ? Kubernetes networking uses iptables to control the network connections between pods (and between nodes), handling many of the networking and port forwarding rules. You can take a look: https://ronaknathani.com/blog/2020/07/kubernetes-nodeport-and-iptables-rules/  Overally to limit access to resources in cluster you could create services - take a look on this doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ using them you will be able to reach pods.

Comment: No I wasn't using any specific tutorial are just based on the general rules I used to use.

Comment: Have you looked at articles I have mentioned ? Also please read: https://www.stackrox.com/post/2020/01/kubernetes-networking-demystified/ https://itnext.io/kubernetes-service-load-balancing-kube-proxy-and-iptables-da3ebf1c802a